# Issues getting Apache VirtualHost to properly Map

Tags: linux, docker, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm setting up a docker container on a linux server and I'm trying to set up a VirtualHost so that when I visit the domain I own it will show that website.

I have a DNS record on my domain to use the IP address of my linux server, and I installed apache on there to test and it worked properly.

If I start my container with

```
docker run -dit --name web-app -p 8080:80 web-image
```

I can go to mydomain.com:8080 and see my website, but it doesn't work if I just navigate to mydomain.com.

My VirtualHost stanza in `httpd.conf` is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

The only thing I can think is that I need to update my domain DNS definition to accept the Docker Container IP address?

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Well if you expose the docker service on port `8080` then it's only available on that port. You have to expose the docker service on port 80 if you want to just enter "mydomain.com" and have the docker service respond. Keep in mind that if your port 80 is already in use it will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite obvious, that the website is available on port `8080`, but not port `80`, since you define `-p 8080:80`. You need to expose port `80` instead.

```
docker run -dit --name web-app -p 80:80 web-image
```

Comment: Duh, that makes sense. I thought I'd tried that before but I guess not.